# For loop to dictionary comprehension correct translation (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I need to find the longest string in a list for each letter of the alphabet.
My first straight forward approach looked like this:

```
alphabet = ["a","b", ..., "z"]
text = ["ane4", "anrhgjt8", "andhjtje9", "ajhe5", "]more_crazy_words"]
result = {key:"" for key in alphabet} # create a dictionary

# go through all words, if that word is longer than the current longest, save it
for word in text: 
    if word[0].lower() in alphabet and len(result[word[0].lower()]) < len(word):
        result[word[0].lower()] = word.lower()
print(result)
```

which returns:

```
{'a': 'andhjtje9'}
```

as it is supposed to do.

In order to practice dictionary comprehension I tried to solve this in just one line:

```
result2 = {key:"" for key in alphabet}
result2 = {word[0].lower(): word.lower() for word in text if word[0].lower() in alphabet and len(result2[word[0].lower()]) < len(word)}
```

I just copied the if statement into the comprehension loop...
results2 however is:

```
{'a': 'ajhe5'}
```

can someone explain me why this is the case? I feel like I did exactly the same as in the first loop...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: you use the previous values of `result2` that keeps having the empty strings as value until the dict comprehension is calculated

Comment: the `for` needs to be on `alphabet` and find the max length word by filtering on first char and construct tuples of `(length, string)`, then find max with a key function and then extract the string of found maximum

Comment: You can apply `groupby()`: `{g: i for g, (*_, i) in groupby(sorted(text, key=lambda x: (len(x), x[0])), itemgetter(0)) if 96 < ord(g) < 123}`. Imports: [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) *(you can replace `itemgetter(0)` with `lambda x: x[0]`)*. I used ascii character codes to filter `a .. z`, check [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set).

Comment: @PatrickArtner, sorry my mistake...it returns 'andhjtje9'...I will edit the post

Comment: @rioV8 thanks, this was basically the explanation i was looking for!
I did not realise that it still compares the values to the empty string, since the new dict is not created yet, whereas in the "classical" for loop it is!

Answer (score 0):

List / Dict / Set - comprehension can not refer to themself while building itself - thats why you do not get what you want.

You *can* use a complicated dictionary comprehension to do this - with help of collections.groupby on a sorted list this could look like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import groupby 

text = ["ane4", "anrhgjt8", "andhjtje9", "ajhe5", "]more_crazy_words"] 

d = {key:sorted(value, key=len)[-1] 
 for key,value in groupby((s for s in sorted(text) 
                           if s[0].lower() in frozenset(ascii_lowercase)), 
                          lambda x:x[0].lower())}
print(d) # {'a': 'andhjtje9'}
```

or

```
text = ["ane4", "anrhgjt8", "andhjtje9", "ajhe5", "]more_crazy_words"] 
 
d = {key:next(value) for key,value in groupby(
    (s for s in sorted(text, key=lambda x: (x[0],-len(x))) 
     if s[0].lower() in frozenset(ascii_lowercase)), 
     lambda x:x[0].lower())}

print(d) # {'a': 'andhjtje9'}
```

or several other ways ... but why would you?

Having it as for loops is much cleaner and easier to understand and would, in this case, follow the zen of python probably better.

Read about the zen of python by running:

```
import this
```

Comment: I also prefer the basic loop version...I was just trying it out to practice it and was confused why this was not working. But thanks for your answer! great solution to the problem :)

Comment: Groupby isn't needed if you just pre-sort by initial letter and length (i.e. last in, wins): `{i[0]: i for i in sorted(map(str.lower, text), key=lambda i: (i[0], len(i))) if i[0] in alphabet}`.

Comment: @ekh with groupby I avoids re-setting the value of one key over and over - yours sets the value for each key to all values, starting with the shortest and then overwriting them with ever longer ones until the longest value survives. Valid approach, I prefer the grouping construct. Thanks for suggesting though.

Comment: @ekhumoro, it's a bit strong to say "not needed", because approach you offered is quite different, it relies on fact that value of key will be rewritten every time. Speaking about "optimizations", you can avoid using `map()` by lowering first char in your lambda expression.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Re-setting the value is exactly what the idiomatic for-loop solution does (i.e. last in, wins). The OP's attempted conversion to a dict comprehension failed because it required a lookup on itself. My solution succeeds because it avoids that lookup by pre-sorting the input. This shows that it's possible to get quite close to what the OP was trying to achieve without using `groupby`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght See my comment above. My approach is very similar to the OP's initial for-loop solution - so not really diffrent at all (compared with using `groupby`, anyway). Also, the use of `map` is more efficient because it avoids calling `lower` twice.

Comment: PS: I just noticed [noV8 suggested a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737908/for-loop-to-dictionary-comprehension-correct-translation-python/64738188?noredirect=1#comment114463202_64737908) quite similar to mine. Also, an even simpler way to fix the OP's solution would be: `{word[0].lower(): word.lower() for word in sorted(text, key=len) if word[0].lower() in alphabet}`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, last solution seems pretty good, only improvement I can advice is to not lower `word[0]` in condition, but use [`ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) instead of `alphabet`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I just did some quick testing, and by far the fastest (and shortest) solution is this: `{i[0]: i for i in sorted(map(str.lower, text), key=len) if i[0] in alphabet}`. Of course, ideally, `alphabet` should be a `set`. If the walrus operator is allowed, a slightly faster solution is `{k:i for i in sorted(map(str.lower, text), key=len) if (k:=i[0]) in alphabet}`.